# Piping data through a dynamic list of functions

Tags: haskell, composition, monoids

So I often find myself designing 'pipeline' like flows of data,
and oftentimes it ends up that the pipeline itself is dynamic.

Is there an easy way to do something like this?

```
pipe :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
```

Or is there a different pattern I should be reaching for with something like this? It's similar to the State monad, but I don't want to have to edit the functions to be `(a -> (), a)` or whatever :/

I realized that this is a monoid, so I wrote this, which seems like an elegant solution, does this exist in a library somewhere? It seems like most Arrow and Function Monoids do different things.

```
newtype Comp a = Comp { 
      runComp :: a -> a 
}

instance Monoid (Comp a) where
  (Comp a) `mappend` (Comp b) =  Comp (b . a)
  mempty = Comp id

pipe :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
pipe = runComp . foldMap Comp
```

Anyone have patterns that they use for this sort of thing? Thanks!

Comment: A morphism from *A*  to *A*  is called an [endomorphism](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo). Your `Comp` monoid is  `Dual . Endo`.

Comment: Polymorphic pipeline? I suspect there might be an X/Y problem here. How do you intend to use this?

Comment: Yes, as @leftaroundabout seems to hint, you only need this fancy machinery if you need to be able to take the list apart, as well as compose the functions in it. Otherwise, you should surely just deal with the composition and get rid of the list.

Comment: @leftaroundabout This is a pattern I often find myself doing, in this particular case it was for an advent of code problem where I had a list of 'commands' that I'd parsed from input, I partially applied the functions which operate over the commands `(CMD -> State -> State)` so I had a list of `State -> State`, then I wanted to feed in my initial `State` and get the result out the end.

Do you have suggestions on how I could do this better :)?

Comment: @Zeta That's exactly what I wanted to know! Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisPenner: there's no need to do that in two steps – why not just `foldl'` over the list of commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for one of

```
foldr (.) id        -- right-to-left
```

or

```
foldl (flip (.)) id -- left-to-right
```

depending on which order you want the functions composed:

```
ghci> foldr (.) id [(+1),(*10)] 0
1
ghci> foldl (flip (.)) id [(+1),(*10)] 0
10
```

Comment: Or, if you want to stay in the fuzzy realm of `Monoid`: `appEndo . foldMap Endo` and `(appEndo . getDual) . foldMap (Dual . Endo)`. By the way, I hope you don't mind the example.

Comment: I usually use `foldr (.) id` for this -- is there any reason to use `foldl` here?

Comment: @Zeta Isn't this again a place to use `stimesMonoid`?

Comment: @Alec: Sorry, "again"? We haven't had a discussion about `stimesMonoid`. And no.

Comment: @chi, Yep, `foldr (.) id` is the productive one: `foldr (.) id (const 7:repeat id) 9 == 7`